# How would I upload music using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, audio, xampp, localhost

I have created a table which contains my music information and album art. I've been using Mysql and PHP to create the table and implement the images. I don't understand how I would upload my music onto this table as well though? Could someone help?

I need my music to show and play in the play column.

[As you can see, on the far right is the play column and the names of the mp3 files are in the play column as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmFoG.png)

[And this is where my audio files are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtC0g.png)

And here is my coding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
     border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "jukebox";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "SELECT * FROM Music";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table>

     <tr>

     <th>Artist</th>
     <th>Title</th>
     <th>Album</th>
     <th>Albumcover</th>
     <th>Play</th>
     </tr>";


// output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

         echo 

         "<tr>

         <td>" . $row["Artist"]. "</td>
         <td>" . $row["Title"]. "</td>
         <td>" . $row["Album"]. "</td>
         <td><img src='/jukebox/img/" . $row["Albumcover"] ."' alt=".$row["Albumcover"]."></td>
         <td>" . $row["Play"]  . "></td>



         </tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";



} else {
     echo "0 results";
}



?>  


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: html tag is available for playing audio. [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp). this may help you

Comment: Where abouts would i put this coding though? And how would I link the music I have saved into my coding?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
echo "<tr>
            <td>" . $row["Artist"]. "</td>
            <td>" . $row["Title"]. "</td>
            <td>" . $row["Album"]. "</td>
            <td><img src='/jukebox/img/" . $row["Albumcover"] ."' alt=".$row["Albumcover"]."></td>
            <td>
               <audio controls>
                  <source src='pathToAudioFile.mp3' type=\"audio/mpeg\">
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
                </audio>
            </td>
         </tr>";
```

Also make sure that the audio file permission is set properly